# Is there a way to change nsimagecell background color?

Tags: cocoa

Is there a way I can change the background color of an nsimagecell? I can easily do this for the text field cells using setBackgroundColor...some code to this solution would be nice! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here is the answer, sharing my first sub-class...

This NSImageCell responds to setBackgroundColor! :)

```
//
//  colorImageCell.h
//  OldFileRemover
//
//  Created by Riz Khan on 16/12/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Riz Khan. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface colorImageCell : NSImageCell

- (void)setImage:(NSImage *)theImage;

- (void)setBackgroundColor:(NSColor *)theColor;

@end


//
//  colorImageCell.m
//  OldFileRemover
//
//  Created by Riz Khan on 16/12/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Riz Khan. All rights reserved.
//

#import "colorImageCell.h"

@implementation colorImageCell

NSColor *cellBGColor;
NSImage *iconImage;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    cellBGColor = [NSColor whiteColor];

    iconImage = nil;

    return self;
}

- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    // if you want the image cell to do what it normally would do as if you hadn't subclassed it, call super:
    [super drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];

    // do the rest of your custom drawing (if any)

    [cellBGColor setFill];

    NSRectFill(cellFrame);

    [iconImage drawInRect:cellFrame fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0f respectFlipped:YES hints:nil];
}

- (void)setImage:(NSImage *)theImage
{
    iconImage = theImage;
}

- (void)setBackgroundColor:(NSColor *)theColor
{
    cellBGColor = theColor;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Need to create subClass of NSImageCell and fill color in drawInrect

or 
2) Not setting BGColor of cell but same look like that

```
NSImageView *image =[[NSImageView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[image setWantsLayer:YES];
[image.layer setBackgroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor].CGColor];
```

Comment: Im using a cell based table, so answer 2 wont work, as for 1, not quite sure how to do that, could you share some code?